# Template alias in template function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

**EDITED:** Let us suposse I have two (or more) template functions `f` and `g` that uses (some times) types depending on its template parameter:

```
template<typename T>
some_ugly_and_large_or_deep_template_struct_1<T>::type 
f(const some_ugly_and_large_or_deep_template_struct_1<T>::type&,
  const some_ugly_and_large_or_deeptemplate_struct_1<T>::type&)
{
   // body, that uses perhaps more times my
   // "some_ugly_and_large_or_deep_template_struct_1<T>"
}

template<typename T>
some_ugly_and_large_or_deep_template_struct_2<T>::type 
g(const some_ugly_and_large_or_deep_template_struct_2<T>::type&,
  const some_ugly_and_large_or_deeptemplate_struct_2<T>::type&)
{
   // body, that uses perhaps more times my
   // "some_ugly_and_large_or_deep_template_struct_2<T>"
}
```

How could I simplify this "type" definition?, for example with any of new C++11's tools? I think only on something like:

```
template<typename T,
         typename aux = some_ugly_and_large_or_deep_template_struct_1<T>::type>
aux f(const aux&, const aux&)
{
  // body, that uses perhaps more times my
  // "aux" type
}

template<typename T,
         typename aux = some_ugly_and_large_or_deep_template_struct_2<T>::type>
aux g(const aux&, const aux&)
{
  // body, that uses perhaps more times my
  // "aux" type
}
```

The problem that I see with this approach is the user can provide his own `aux` type and not the type that I want.

Comment: To ensure the type is what you want you could use `static_assert` with `std::is_same`.

Comment: @hmjd But I should to 'write' two times a line containing `some_ugly_and_large_or_deep_template_struct<T>::type` and I could have a lot of functions with the same problem (and also that reduces readability).

Comment: with a macro? : #define DEEP_TYPE(T) some_ugly_and_large_or_deep_template_struct<T>::type

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you make it a variadic template, the caller has no possibility to define the type parameters listed after:

```
template<typename T,
         typename..., // firewall, absorbs all supplied arguments
         typename aux = some_ugly_and_large_or_deep_template_struct_1<T>::type>
aux f(const aux&, const aux&)
{
  // body, that uses perhaps more times my
  // "aux" type
}
```

Optionally, to prevent calling `f` accidentally with too many template arguments, one can add a static_assert:

```
template<typename T,
         typename... F,
         typename aux = some_ugly_and_large_or_deep_template_struct_1<T>::type>
aux f(const aux&, const aux&)
{
  static_assert(sizeof...(F)==0, "Too many template arguments");
  // body, that uses perhaps more times my
  // "aux" type
}
```

Usually, I can live with letting the user define types like `aux`, being for example the return type where this can save you a cast.

Or you can replace the `static_assert` with an `enable_if`:

```
template<typename T,
         typename... F, typename = typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(F)==0>::type,
         typename aux = some_ugly_and_large_or_deep_template_struct<T>::type,>
aux f(const aux&, const aux&)
{
  // body, that uses perhaps more times my                                               
  // "aux" type                                                                          
}
```

Comment: Excelent trick the variadic template :) Is it possible to combine the variadic template with a `enable_if` to erase the `static_assert`?

Comment: Is it possible to create a `class` that make the firewall and the `sizeof` check, and put this `class` as template parameter? The idea is simplify it the most possible, because I have the same problem in lots of points of my code.

Answer (score 2):

You could declare a template alias alongside the function:

```
template<typename T> using f_parameter
  = typename some_ugly_and_large_or_deep_template_struct<T>::type;

template<typename T>
f_parameter<T> f(const f_parameter<T>&, const f_parameter<T>&)
{
   f_parameter<T> param;
}
```

Comment: Better, but this "alias" is defined in the entire compiling unit from its definition point until its end, and perhaps I have diferent functions with diferent `f_parameters`.

Comment: +1 I was wondering if `using` would provide a solution here but the syntax escaped me.

Comment: @Peregring-lk so you write `f_parameter` and `g_parameter`, possibly placing them in a `detail` namespace.

Comment: @hmjd syntax for templates is always crazy hehe

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution would be to convert the template function into a `template struct` with an `operator()`. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
struct some_ugly_and_large_or_deep_template_struct
{
    typedef T type;
};

template <typename T>
struct f
{
    typedef typename some_ugly_and_large_or_deep_template_struct<T>::type aux;

    aux operator()(const aux& a1, const aux& a2)
    {
        return a1 + a2;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << f<int>()(4, 4) << "\n";
    std::cout << f<std::string>()("hello ", "world") << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good, but one objections: if do I have lots of functions, and each one with a diferent `some_ugly_and_large_or_deep_template_struct`?

Comment: @Peregring-lk, I am unsure what you mean exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like

```
namespace f_aux {
   template <typename T> using type = 
            typename some_ugly_and_large_or_deep_template_struct<T>::type;
}

template <typename T>
f_aux::type<T> f(const f_aux::type<T>& , const f_aux::type<T>&);
```

If the declaration of f is in a suitable namespace or class, you may not need the additional `f_aux` namespace.